# Chrome data compression proxy for PC

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy, android, compression

Google Chrome recently introduced data compression proxy which saves bandwith up to %50 in Chrome beta. (https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/data-compression) Sadly it is only available for Android. Is there a way/hack to enable this feature on PC? (preferably windows).

PS: I'm currently using Opera 15.x but I don't find it as good as Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Data Compression Proxy for Google Chrome on Desktop (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajfiodhbiellfpcjjedhmmmpeeaebmep).

Latest version as of this writing is 1.0, released February 16 2014:

> This is an **experimental** extension for Google Chrome bringing Chrome
>   Data Compression Proxy from mobile to desktop PCs.
>
> How it works:
>
> The extension sends all HTTP (but not HTTPS) traffic through Chrome
>   Data Compression Proxy server, which uses SPDY protocol to speed up
>   web browsing. Enabled state is indicated by a green icon. You can
>   manually disable the proxy by clicking on the icon. When the proxy
>   raises an error, it is being automatically disabled for 30 sec, so
>   that the request can be resent.
>
> The extension uses either chrome.webRequest (slower) in Chrome Stable
>   or chrome.declarativeWebRequest (faster) in Chrome Beta/Dev, so ignore
>   any warnings.
>
> Statistics:
>
> You can find the savings statistics at
>   chrome://net-internals/#bandwidth
>
> [image]

Comment: Please provide a bit more details.

Comment: Have you used this addon before. Can you confirm it works?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my extension! Should you have any further questions, ask me.